# Bootstrap 4 JS menu tab

Tags: javascript, html, web, bootstrap-4

i have this code and its working but not properly.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
    <strong>Ⅰ. Main A</strong>
    <ul class="nav flex-column list-style">
        <li class=""><a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#item1">A 1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#item2">A 2</a></li>
        <li class=""><a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#item3">A 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <strong>Ⅱ Main B</strong>
    <ul class="nav flex-column list-style">
        <li class=""><a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#item4">B 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-8 border-left ">
    <div class="tab-content ">
        <div class="tab-pane scroll-able" id="item1">
            <h3>A 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane scroll-able" id="item2">
            <h3>A 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane scroll-able" id="item3">
            <h3>A 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane scroll-able" id="item4">
            <h3>B 1</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i click each once its showing the content correctly
but its not working properly and leaving the active and show class when i click on different submenu (ex. B1 and A3 back-and-forth )

my data is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played a bit and noticed what you reported, then I went to Bootstrap source which tells it is a BS limitation (see [show](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/tab.js#L69) method).

Then the simple options I see are basically 2:

1. Handle the tabs clicks manually: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#via-javascript
   ***Working example***: https://codepen.io/cdtapay/pen/bzegNB
2. Not being semantic and keeping all of the links in the same list (`ul`), including the section labels. ***Working example***: https://codepen.io/cdtapay/pen/QYNRwb

*Hope it helps.*

**UPDATE**
: There is an issue reported about the `show` class being leaked: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28118

Comment: i want to try your option number 1 but i can't seems to understand it. but you solve it anyway.

Comment: @jeesoon I just added a working example for option 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it on codepen, and it works like a charm, the active class is removed when clicking another toggle.

https://codepen.io/fazlurr/pen/QYNPBe

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
    <strong>Ⅰ. Main A</strong>
    <ul class="nav flex-column list-style">
        <li class=""><a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#item1">A 1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#item2">A 2</a></li>
        <li class=""><a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#item3">A 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <strong>Ⅱ Main B</strong>
    <ul class="nav flex-column list-style">
        <li class=""><a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#item4">B 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-8 border-left ">
    <div class="tab-content ">
        <div class="tab-pane scroll-able" id="item1">
            <h3>A 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane scroll-able" id="item2">
            <h3>A 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane scroll-able" id="item3">
            <h3>A 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane scroll-able" id="item4">
            <h3>B 1</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe the way you generate the ids is not right.